# Two functions in a button in vuejs

Tags: button, vue.js

I want to check if the button is selected already and fire a function and if nor selected fire another function, How to do that using vuejs

Comment: Please post the code you got so far. And with selected you mean focussed? Or clicked?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/16wp2wao/

There are some more concise ways to do this, but this is the simplest to see what's going on. The idea is to store states for things in the data property, so when the button has been selected, simply set the selected state to true.

```
var myVueInstance = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: function () {
    return {
        buttonIsSelected: false,
      message: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleClick: function(){
        if ( this.buttonIsSelected == true ){
        this.whenSelected()
      } else {
        this.whenNotSelected()
      }

      //now set the selected state to true
      this.buttonIsSelected = true;

    },
    whenSelected: function(){
        this.message = "The button was clicked - it was already selected"
    },
    whenNotSelected: function(){
    this.message = "The button was clicked - it was not already selected"
    }
  }
});
```